# How to detect an object across overlapping cameras

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, computer-vision

I have a multiple camera setup but I'm narrowing it down to two cameras for this question. The two cameras are aligned and the right side of camera 1 overlaps the left side of camera 2 to ensure no area is left out of sight.
[image: Camera layout]
Both cameras share a common reference system i.e: the x axis in the image 2 is the continuity of the x axis in image 1.

I have no problem for simple scenarios like the following picture when the object is fully contained in one image :[image: scenario 1]

**My problem:**

I don't know how to proceed when the object is across this overlapping area like in the picture below.[image: scenario 2]For my application I need to return for each detect object : center point (x,y), height of the bounding box and width of the bounding box.

**My approach so far:**

I'm using for both images `cv2.findContours` and `cv2.boundingRect`. I calculate based on size of the rect and size of the image if the object touches either side of the image. If they don't it's the easy part but if they do that's were I am stuck at the moment. I don't know how to juggle between the values of both images and creating a unique (x,y,w,h) point from both contours.

There is my current code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread('image_from_cam1.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('image_from_cam2.png')
gray1= cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray2= cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img1_width = img1.shape[1]
img2_width = img2.shape[1]

#Thresholds on both images then find the contours
ret1, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray1, 127, 255, 1)
ret2, thresh2 = cv2.threshold(gray2, 127, 255, 1)
cnts1, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh1, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts2, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh2, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

result = [] #result list that will contain [(x1,y1,w1,h1), ...]
overlap = False #is the object overlapping across several images
l1 = [] #storage list for sub-results in image1
l2 = [] #storage list for sub-results in image2

#loop over contours of image1 to draw rectangles and check if they touch either left of right border
for cnt in cnts1:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(img1, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0), 2)
    #Test if the bounding box touches the border of the screen
    if x<2 or (x+w)>(img1_width - 2):
        overlap = True
        l1.append((x,y,w,h))
    else:
        #the object is fully contained in image1
        result.append((x,y,w,h))

#loop over contours of image2 to draw rectangles and check if they touch either left of right border
for cnt in cnts2:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(img2, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0), 2)
    #Test if the bounding box touches the border of the screen
    if x<2 or (x+w)>(img2_width - 2):
        overlap = True
        l2.append((x,y,w,h))
    else:
        #the object is fully contained in image2
        result.append((x,y,w,h))

cv2.imshow('cam1',img1)
cv2.imshow('cam2',img2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So the same object will give me 2 different sets of (x,y,w,h) with `cv2.boundingRect` in the two images. How can I get the "real" (x,y,w,h) of the object ? Or from my code : how can I create `result` from `l1` and `l2` in case of an overlapping object ?

Comment: Can you show the actual images?

Comment: If your camera are fixed, then you can calculate the transformation matrix between the camera, then stitch them together, so you can get a whole image.

Comment: Yes my cameras are fixed. If I stitch them together with this method @Silencer will the resulted whole image contain the overlapping areas ?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a year late but someone else might find this useful.

One possible solution is:
If your Y axes will always be aligned then define a new coordinate system with a single X and Y axes. So you will always have only two axes for any pair of images.

Get the corresponding X values from the left frame and subtract the overlapping pixels.
Assuming x = 0 from left.
Roughly:

```
if x_main <= x_left_max:
    x_main = x_left
else:
    x_main = x_left_max + (x_right - overlap)
```

Create a converter function and always deal with objects in your custom coordinate space.